# Mouse cursor very slight difference

Tags: notebooks

Mathematica uses a very thin, translucent cursor in Input style cells.
But in text style cells Mathematica uses a cursor theme from Windows. How do I make the cursor visible as normal?

photos of display:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's a way to do this. Looking at old similar, but unanswered questions didn't turn up anything either.

Comment: You pictures make the cursor seem less visible than it actually is on my screen. I don't see much difference between the cursors used in the various cell types either. By the way, you're talking about the insertion marker, not the mouse cursor right?

Comment: To me they look rather similar in terms of visibility (on my computer, not in your screenshots)--the cursor used for the input cell differs from the text one by having more curved cross-bars at the ends and an extra cross-bar in the middle. So, I'm not sure what's going on with your system, but I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to be like that.

Comment: Sjoerd C. de Vries, I talking about I-beam cursor for input cells - http://www.betalogue.com/images/uploads/pages/Pages-MousePointer-Ibeam.gif.

Comment: On my screen it have light gray colour. It would be great, if i-beam have black colour. On win vista I don`t have this problem, now intalled win7x64.

Answer (score 1):

I changed  GrayLevel to 0.8 for Background in OptionInspector and now i-beam cursor have inverse black color - normal recognition white color. Why OptionInspector don`t have any options for i-beam? [image]

Comment: After  installation new driver for ati videocard v13.251  cursor are very crisp. Problem solved!